# Use of ternary operator in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure that return records where

```
 p.FSAProduct != 'Cash Account' AND at.AssetLiabilityType='Book Value'
```

I need to reuse this procedure to return

```
p.FSAProduct == 'Cash Account' AND at.AssetLiabilityType='Book Value'
```

I was trying to use IIF condition but not getting it right. I have also introduced an input variable `@isCollateral`

```
 (   p.FSAProduct != IIF(@isCollateral <> 0, 'Cash Account',null)  AND at.AssetLiabilityType='Book Value') OR
    (   p.FSAProduct == IIF(@isCollateral == 0, 'Cash Account',null)  AND at.AssetLiabilityType='Book Value')
```

Here is the complete stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetNFSRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition]
    @RunContextID bigint,
    @isCollateral bit
AS
    SELECT 
        c.CifID AS CifId, 
        nd.SettlementCurrencyCode AS CurrencyCode, 
        SUM(a.RegUsdAmount) As RegUsdAmount, 
        CASE 
           WHEN AssetLiabilityType='Book Value' THEN SettlementDate 
           ELSE AppliedDate 
        END AS FlowDate,
        p.FuturesType AS FuturesType, 
        p.SwapType AS SwapType, 
        t.SettlementType AS SettlementType, 
        p.FSAProduct AS FsaProduct, 
        CAST(CASE WHEN nd.DerivativeTradeID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS NettingFlag
    FROM 
        ALDB_Trade t 
    INNER JOIN 
        ALDB_AssetLiability a ON t.TradeID = a.TradeID
    INNER JOIN 
        ALDB_AssetLiabilityType at ON at.AssetLiabilityTypeID = a.AssetLiabilityTypeID
    INNER JOIN 
        ALDB_Counterparty c ON c.CounterpartyID = t.CounterpartyID
    INNER JOIN 
        dev_vw_ProductAttributes p ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID
    INNER JOIN 
        ALDB_Company tc ON tc.CompanyID = t.CompanyID
    INNER JOIN 
        ALDB_Company cc ON c.CompanyID = cc.CompanyID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ALDB_RCCNetting nd ON t.TradeID = nd.DerivativeTradeID
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[ALDB_SignificantCurrency] sc ON sc.CurrencyCode = nd.SettlementCurrencyCode
    WHERE 
        p.RunContextID = @RunContextID 
        AND sc.RunContextId = @RunContextID 
        AND t.IsInternal = 0 
        AND tc.CompanyCode IN ('5044','5121') 
        AND NOT ((tc.CompanyCode = '5044' AND cc.CompanyCode = '5121') 
                 OR (tc.CompanyCode = '5121' AND cc.CompanyCode = '5044'))
        AND (p.FSAProduct != 'Cash Account' AND at.AssetLiabilityType = 'Book Value')
    GROUP BY  
        CifID, SettlementCurrencyCode, AssetLiabilityType, AppliedDate,
        SettlementDate, FuturesType, SettlementType, SwapType, FSAProduct,
        CAST(CASE WHEN nd.DerivativeTradeID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit)  
    ORDER BY 
        CifID
GO
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The second part that i have asked I need to reuse this procedure to return

Comment: p.FSAProduct == 'Cash Account' AND at.AssetLiabilityType='Book Value'

Answer (score 0):

From your examples and script, it seems you are simply amending your `where` clause from:

```
where Expr1
  and Expr2
  and Expr3
  and Expr4
```

to:

```
where Expr1
  and Expr2
  and Expr3
  and Expr4 or Expr5
```

Is this correct?

If so, you will get problems because SQL Server does not execute the expressions in any implicit grouping or order.  You need to explicitly group your expressions, like so:

```
where Expr1
  and Expr2
  and Expr3
  and (Expr4 or Expr5)
```

In your case, this would mean adding some wrapping parentheses around your attempted expression:

```
((p.FSAProduct <> IIF(@isCollateral <> 0, 'Cash Account',null)
  AND at.AssetLiabilityType='Book Value'
 )
 OR
 (p.FSAProduct = IIF(@isCollateral = 0, 'Cash Account',null)
  AND at.AssetLiabilityType='Book Value'
 )
)
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error in the or part . Error says incorrect syntax near @isCollateral. Expecting '(' or Select

Comment: @Tom  Are you using a `==` double equals?  If so, SQL Server syntax is just the one `=` when doing comparisons